# limit div float clears to within a nested div

Tags: css-float

I have a two div columns (ColumnA and ColumnB) within MasterParent div. These two columns are using float:left. OK no problem. works.

Now, within ColumnB I want 3 more separate columns (Column1,2,3).

I float column1,2,3 all left so they butt up together but when I go to start a new line and clear the previous column floats, it clears all the way up to the MasterParent and drops the next line below the horizontal position of the bottom of ColumnA.

Is there a way to only clear up through ColumnB and not all the way up to the MasterPArent div?

Answer (score 1):

You can not clear anything, and add `overflow: hidden` to your MasterParent div. Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durilai/2GjRa/).

Here is the code:

```
.Container
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.Col1
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.Col2
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.Col2a
{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.Col2b
{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.Col2c
{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

<div class="Container">
    <div class="Col1">
        <p>Column 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Col2">
        <p>Column 2</p>
        <div class="Col2a">2a</div>
        <div class="Col2b">2b</div>
        <div class="Col2c">2c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Dustin! You helped me immensly... I wasn't placing a width on Column 2c which was making excess text fall back to the beginning of 2a